# Is it possible to use indexing in turtle objects?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm working on an Agar.io game in turtle. I've looped food objects to avoid writing separate lines of code. Objects are displayed on the screen, but when calling them in the main loop, in the part responsible for collision, only one object from the loop works. If I create objects line by line, all work but it is not elegant.

I receive UnboundLocalError: local variable 'pos' referenced before assignment:

```
#food
dist = 20 #### distance between agario and food
food = ['af','af2','af3','af4']
food2 = []
for z in range(4):
    food[z] = t.Turtle()
    food[z].shape("square")
    food[z].turtlesize(0.8,0.8,0.8)
    food[z].color("green")
    food[z].speed(0)
    food[z].penup()
    x = r.randint(-290, 290)
    y = r.randint(-240, 240)
    food[z].goto(x, y)
    food2.append(food[z])

while True:
#contact with food
    if a.distance(food2) < dist:
        dist = dist + 1
        x = r.randint(-290, 290)
        y = r.randint(-240, 240)
        food2.goto(x,y)
```

traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/projects/agario.py", line 118, in <module>
    kb.setx(kb.xcor() + kb.dx)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\turtle.py", line 1808, in setx
    self._goto(Vec2D(x, self._position[1]))
  File "C:\Python37\lib\turtle.py", line 3158, in _goto
    screen._pointlist(self.currentLineItem),
  File "C:\Python37\lib\turtle.py", line 755, in _pointlist
    cl = self.cv.coords(item)
  File "<string>", line 1, in coords
  File "C:\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2469, in coords
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'coords') + args))]
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas"
```

Comment: The code you've shown does not seem related to the error message. "pos" does not appear anywhere. Please show the full error message including traceback, and the relevant code.

Comment: @mkrieger1  File "c:/projects/agario.py", line 155, in <module>
    if a.distance(food2) < dist:
  File "C:\Python37\lib\turtle.py", line 1858, in distance
    return abs(pos - self._position)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'pos' referenced before assignment

Comment: @babcia.nazgul Please use the 'edit' button if you want to add more content to your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This logic:

```
food = ['af','af2','af3','af4']
food2 = []
for z in range(4):
    food[z] = t.Turtle()
```

is effectively trying to do:

```
'af2' = t.Turtle()
```

which isn't going to work.  You should use a dictionary if you need symbols like `'af2'`, otherwise, clean up the array logic:

```
# food
dist = 20  # distance between agario and food
food = []

for _ in range(4):
    morsel = t.Turtle("square")
    morsel.turtlesize(0.8, 0.8, 0.8)
    morsel.color("green")
    morsel.speed('fastest')
    morsel.penup()
    x = r.randint(-290, 290)
    y = r.randint(-240, 240)
    morsel.goto(x, y)
    food.append(morsel)

while True:
    # contact with food
    for morsel in food:
        if a.distance(morsel) < dist:
            dist += 1
            x = r.randint(-290, 290)
            y = r.randint(-240, 240)
            morsel.goto(x, y)
```

I don't have enough of your code to test this, so it's just a guess.

Comment: Thanks it worked ! :) I did try something similiar before but unfortunately with no effect. Could please confirm if morsel is something specific and same with floor in for section, or it is just how you call it ?

Comment: @babcia.nazgul, I don't fully understand your question but `morsel` (a small piece of food) is just an arbitrary variable name.  (Well, less arbitrary than `z`, I guess.)